# Android's Surface class gives me an "already connected" error, and a IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am calling:

```
mSurface.lockCanvas(null);
```

Null is an acceptable parameter to give lockCanvas, indicating that the entire screen needs to be updated.

The surface I am using is being passed to me, and the code that obtains it does so through:

```
new Surface(mPlaybackView.getSurfaceTexture());
```

mPlaybackView is a TextureView that is grabbed from Resources.  When lockCanvas(null) is called, I get the following:

```
BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-6903-1] connect(P): already connected (cur=3 req=2)
```

and

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas (Native Method).
```

I am stumped, as I am still learning about the canvas and surface and etc.

Is there something obviously wrong here?

Edit: Here's the stack trace.

```
    11-19 09:45:28.075 3319-3319/com.example.eschjen.nov15test D/Jenny: inside try, surface is: Surface(name=android.graphics.SurfaceTexture@10e80e42)/@0x3bc8b489
11-19 09:45:28.086 3319-3319/com.example.eschjen.nov15test E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-3319-0] connect(P): already connected (cur=3 req=2)
11-19 09:45:28.087 3319-3319/com.example.eschjen.nov15test E/Jenny: Exception caught: 
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                        at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:255)
                                                                        at com.example.eschjen.nov15test.MediaCodecWrapper.surfaceRender(MediaCodecWrapper.java:469)
                                                                        at com.example.eschjen.nov15test.MediaCodecWrapper.access$200(MediaCodecWrapper.java:41)
                                                                        at com.example.eschjen.nov15test.MediaCodecWrapper$1.outputSample(MediaCodecWrapper.java:338)
                                                                        at com.example.eschjen.nov15test.MediaCodecWrapper.popSampleJenny(MediaCodecWrapper.java:345)
                                                                        at com.example.eschjen.nov15test.MainActivity$1.onTimeUpdate(MainActivity.java:183)
                                                                        at android.animation.TimeAnimator.animationFrame(TimeAnimator.java:27)
                                                                        at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1248)
                                                                        at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:659)
                                                                        at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:682)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-19 09:45:28.087 3319-3319/com.example.eschjen.nov15test D/Jenny: done trying
11-19 09:45:28.088 3319-3319/com.example.eschjen.nov15test D/Jenny: done being synchronized.
```

Comment: Could you post the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take that `mPlaybackView` is a `TextureView`. `Surface.lockCanvas(rect)` can throw `IllegalArgumentException` **if the 'rect' rectangle is not valid.**

> E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-3319-0] connect(P): already connected
>   (cur=3 req=2)

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) in `TextureView`:

> A TextureView's SurfaceTexture can be obtained either by invoking
>   getSurfaceTexture() or by using a TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener.
>   It is important to know that a SurfaceTexture is available only after
>   the TextureView is attached to a window (and onAttachedToWindow() has
>   been invoked.) It is therefore highly recommended you use a listener
>   to be notified when the SurfaceTexture becomes available.
>   It is important to note that only one producer can use the TextureView. **For instance, if you use a TextureView to display the camera preview, you cannot use lockCanvas() to draw onto the TextureView at the same time.**

You need to make sure that the `SurfaceTexture` associated with this `TextureView` is available for rendering. You can use `TextureView.isAvailable()` to confirm that.

Comment: isAvailable() returns true.

Comment: Yes. But seems like your problem here is because the surface is owned by a different producer. Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#lockCanvas()

Comment: *thinking*. It's possible the video player thinks it owns the texture view. I'll look into this avenue.  Nothing is displaying anything on screen, though, so if the video player thinks it owns it, it's wrong.

Comment: Having two separate TextViews fixes the problem. I'll go from here to figure out if there's a way to keep the first texture view from thinking it has a "producer". Thanks!

Comment: Hi guys. I found that after the call

`myFrameLayout.removeView (myTextureView); `
`myFrameLayout.addView (myTextureView);`

myTextureView was disconnected from the parent FrameLayout, but I couldn't find a method to check if myTextureView is already connected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was switching cameras with same `TextureView` and `SurfaceTexture`. Same error `already connected` For me `surface.release` works. Some code snippet for your reference:

Do this when starting camera

```
if (previewSurfaceTarget == null) previewSurfaceTarget = new Surface(mPreviewSurfaceTexture);
```

Do this before restarting

```
if (null != mCameraDevice) {
    mCameraDevice.close();
    mCameraDevice = null;
    mCameraIsOpen = false;
}

if (previewSurfaceTarget != null)
previewSurfaceTarget.release();
previewSurfaceTarget = null;
```